# Twisted client failed to connect working differently on Windows to Linux/MacOS

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I am trying to detect a failed connection when using the Twisted endpoint connect() function.  What is odd is that the following works under Windows and gives the expected result, but on a Linux/Mac OS system I am never seeing the print statement from errBack.  Is my code incorrect or does Windows Twisted work differently from the rest?

```
class Gateway():
    def __init__(self):

        from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
        endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, 'localhost', 8000)
        authInterfaceFactory = AuthInterfaceFactory(self.__authMsgProcessor)
        d = endpoint.connect(authInterfaceFactory)
        d.addErrback(self.ConnFailed)
        print("WAITING...")

    def ConnFailed(self, msg):
        print("[DEBUG] Errback : {0}".format(msg))
```

### Windows Result

> WAITING... [DEBUG] Errback : [Failure instance: Traceback (failure
>   with no frames): : Connection was
>   refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it..]

I created a client that uses endpoint connect and it immediately returned, although when used it in the same setup as my code it doesn't:

```
    self.__networkThread = threading.Thread(target=reactor.run,
        kwargs={"installSignalHandlers": False})
    self.__networkThread.start()

    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
    endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, 'localhost', 8000)
    d = endpoint.connect(authInterfaceFactory)
    d.addErrback(self.ConnFailed)
    d.addCallback(self.ConnOK)
```

Is the logic incorrect when running a reactor in a thread (I have to as I want it started at the beginning)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the reactor in one thread and use Twisted APIs in another.  Apart from a couple APIs dedicated specifically to interacting with threads, you must use all Twisted APIs from a single thread.

"I want it started at the beginning" doesn't sound like a reason to use threads.  Many many Twisted-using programs start the reactor "at the beginning" without threads.

(Also please take this as an excellent example of the need for *complete* examples.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I added a callback to success and on Linux/Mac it still sits there and does nothing.  I used telnet to port 8000 and got immediate error

Comment: $ telnet localhost 8000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Probably time to get tcpdump and/or dtrace involved.